# How does getTail() method in XMLFormatter work?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

There's a method in java.util.logging.XMLFormatter called getTail() which writes the last line of a physical log file. It simply writes

```
</log>
```

on a line by itself.

Does anyone know how/when getTail() is invoked? I've never called it in my own code and it has always written that last line anyway. Now, suddenly, it is not. I've apparently broken something but I'm darned if I can think of what I did or how to fix this. My log file is written but I can't open it. A companion file, which appears to be a lock, makes sure of that. (If the log file name is Fuzz.log.xml, the other file will be called Fuzz.log.xml.lck and its file size is 0. If I delete that file, I can edit my log file again and it's fine except that it's missing the final log tag.) I just want the logging code to write that tag for me again so that I can open the log without deleting the lock file and manually adding the  tile.

What stupid thing could I have done to keep getTail() from working??

Comment: Maybe a different question will help me get to the root of the problem. What process closes a physical log file? In other words, when a log file normally close so that I don't have to delete the lock file and add the </log> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would expect that the JDK Logging Framework takes care of the stream-handling. If you look at where "getTail()" is called, you see that it is invoked as part of StreamHandler.flushAndClose(), this is mainly called from StreamHandler.close().

So the tail is written whenever the stream for the logging functionality is closed correctly, i.e. when the application terminates gracefully. If the application is crashing or killed, it may not have a chance to close the file correctly.

The best way to look at these things is probably to use Eclipse and ensure that the JDK Source is available in the Preferences under "Java -> Installed JREs", then you can use all the Eclipse browsing functionality to see where things are connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can force closing thus:

```
FileHandler fileHandler = (FileHandler) yourLogger.getHandlers()[0];
fileHandler.flush();
fileHandler.close();
```

I'm assuming the first handler exists and It is a file handler. It's on you manage this situation.